# How do I pass a string to a linked list instead of an array of characters in C?

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I understand that there's no String data type in C. What I want to do is get an input string from the user and store it to a variable without having to define how many characters it needs to have. Can I do that using linked lists? I want to avoid putting it to a character array as much as possible so linked lists are the only thing I can think of but I don't know how to.

Comment: You can dynamically create an array of chars. That's better than a linked list in size and versatility. Why do you want to avoid character arrays?

Comment: It's one of the requirements in my homework. Oh, I forgot to tag this with homework. Let me edit the question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do it in a linked list, but a linked list of char will generally be an extremely inefficient data structure -- each node will have one char and (at least) one pointer. In a typical case, you're looking at 4 or 8 bytes for the pointer and one for the char, so you're imposing a *lot* of overhead.

My immediate recommendation would be to put at least 16 characters in each node in your linked list to keep the overhead at least sort of reasonable. Of course, a dynamic array will usually be better still, but at least that will keep a linked list from being *totally* unreasonable.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a linked list, but the more usual approach is to allocate a block of memory with `malloc()` and dynamically resize that block with `realloc()` if the user input exceeds the bounds of the array.

> #### void *malloc(size_t size);
>
> The `malloc()` function allocates size bytes of memory and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.
>
> #### void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
>
> The `realloc()` function tries to change the size of the allocation pointed to by *ptr* to size, and
>        returns *ptr*.  If there is not enough room to enlarge the memory allocation pointed to by *ptr*, `realloc()`
>        creates a new allocation, copies as much of the old data pointed to by *ptr* as will fit to the new allocation, frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  If *ptr* is NULL, `realloc()` is identical to a call to `malloc()` for *size* bytes.  If *size* is zero and *ptr* is not NULL, a new, minimum sized object is allocated and the original object is freed.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1. calculate the length of string that will be needed (e.g. counting the number of chars until a newline is seen) then allocate a dynamic array using malloc(), this requires two-pass over the input string, OR
2. if it is impossible to precalculate how long an array should be, then you can malloc() a fixed amount of array, read from the user, then realloc() if the allocated size isn't big enough. This requires an n-pass, where n is the number of realloc() made.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure you do this with a char pointer.

```
char* storedString;

void storeString(char* inputString)
{
  char* s = storedString; // temporary handler
  while(++s = ++inputString); // copy string
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  storeString("hello");
  // you can now treat storedString as if it was an array of chars
  // containing: 'h'+'e'+'l'+'l'+'o'+'\0'
}
```

Comment: This *may* work if the programmer knows the text he/she needs ahead of time, but there's a few other things about this code that I don't like. These least of which is a global variable and a sketchy while loop that appears infinite. Edit: Have you run this code?

Comment: you never allocates memory for storedString, so storedString is only a pointer to a single char, not a pointer to an array of chars. This will cause you to write to a memory address that you should not be able to write; and either cause a segmentation fault or random data corruption.

Comment: @Lie: slightly wrong, `storedString` is a NULL pointer because global variables are zero-initialized.